# Convert Daily Data to Monthly Data in Python : Time Series Analysis

Tags: python

I am new to data analysis with python. I have daily data of flu cases for a five year period which I want to do Time Series Analysis on. Am using the Pandas library. It is easy to plot this data and see the trend over time, however now I want to see seasonality. As it is, the daily data when plotted is too dense (because it's daily) to see seasonality well and I would like to transform/convert the data (pandas DataFrame) into monthly data so I can better see seasonality. Is there an easy way to do this with pandas (or any other python data munging library)?

Comment: Why not smooth the data rather than coarsen them so drastically?

Comment: +1 to @whuber There is no magic to monthly reduction when the data are daily. A month does not have physical or epidemiological meaning. (The fact that many other datasets are reported monthly doesn't mean that you have to mimic that form.)

Answer (score 3):

There are examples of doing what you want in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling). In pandas the method is called `resample`.

```
monthly_x = x.resample('M')
```

Or this is an example of a monthly seasonal plot for daily data in [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.month_plot.html#statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.month_plot) may be of interest.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
dta = sm.datasets.elnino.load_pandas().data
dta['YEAR'] = dta.YEAR.astype(int).astype(str)
dta = dta.set_index('YEAR').T.unstack()
dates = map(lambda x : pd.datetools.parse('1 '+' '.join(x)),
                                       dta.index.values)
dta.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dates, freq='M')
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.month_plot(dta)
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly does "resample" do?  *How* does it compute monthly values from daily ones and why would it be reasonable to use it for this particular dataset and for the purpose of detecting seasonality?

Comment: I just added the stackoverflow answer to the question as asked. The linked documentation should get a user all the way there. By default, resample takes the mean when downsampling data though arbitrary transformations are possible.

Comment: Incidentally, you could do smoothing using statsmodels and/or pandas but these are software questions.

Comment: As I read it, the heart of this question is "I want to see seasonality." Although this is comprised of two separate follow-on requests--to downsample and to provide Python implementations--the issue that is relevant for this site and (I would argue) of far greater value to the OP concerns how to visualize seasonality in a time series dataset. Don't you think that has to be addressed before recommending a solution?